# How can I check photograph quality?

Tags: c#, .net, noise, photography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check out the picture quality in program using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532794/how-can-i-check-out-the-picture-quality-in-program-using-c)

Can I check whether noise is added to a photograph using c#?

Comment: Noise specifically? or tampering?

Comment: Some references ... 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_quality
http://www.mitre.org/tech/mtf/

Comment: Without access to the original photo?  Are you looking to detect specific algorithmic patterns of artificially created noise?
Or are you just looking to detect noise in an image?

Comment: By having the original image identify whether noise is added.If noise added is very low can approve to print.That what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to detect noise what I think you are going to want to do is find pixels that are discontinuous (in color or brightness) from other pixels.

In any given photograph, a valid pixel is highly likely to be correlated (similar) in color or intensity to one or more pixels around it.  Noise is not the same (or similar) color as any other pixel around it; it is discontinuous from all surrounding pixels.

If a pixel is similar or identical in color to surrounding pixels, it is probably not noise, and it's not going to look like noise; it's going to look like part of the picture..